# Number of rows with specific text

Tags: excel

How to get the number of rows which includes A, AA, AAA, AB, AAC etc.? On the following example result is 2. If the same row has A on different shapes on many cells it's only calculated as one.

Cell A1: AA, B1: A, A2: AAABABC, A3: BC

The following only calculates if rows has one A but not rows with AA or AAA

```
=SUM(--(MMULT(--(A1:C10="A"); TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:C10)))>0))
```

The following calculates how many A's one row has but not the amount of rows.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN($A1:$C10)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A1:$C10;"A";"")))/LEN(1))
```

Comment: So are you interested in checking the *whole* rows or just column A-C for any value holding "A"? Also, what version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Whole rows holding value A, AA or AAA (seven columns at least). The version of Excel is Microsoft Excel for Mac 16.36.

Comment: You don't want to include AAAA AAAAA etc. (if they occur) ?

Comment: Would be great, that may occur too. Background: Every letter is one working shift and there may be many of them per 24 hours. Different letters are different kind of shifts. Every row is a different person and every column is a day of the year. So, I need to know the number of rows which includes A.

Comment: The number of rows of letter A is collected per week (seven columns). It's okay to use numbers instead of letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to count how many rows contain at least one A, it should just be a slight alteration to your MMULT formula:

```
=SUM(--(MMULT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND("A",A1:C10))), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:C10)))>0))
```

entered as an Array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you Tom! Just what I was looking for.